Firebase: Understanding reads and caching
I am trying to understand whether I need to implement additional logic for caching to reduce the number of reads for my future app.
I have read about Firebase and it seems as if I am only charged reads if a document is not already in the cache. That is, if I query an entire collection, but only one document is new, I am only charged one read as long as I have enabled persistence and caching. Is that correct?
If it is, it seems that Firebase comes with all the caching logic one needs to prevent unnecessary reads with every app start. Say I have about 500 documents overall in my DB and 10000 daily users, then, given I do not create new documents, I will have only

new users * 500 + existing users * app starts * queries per session

reads, as one read is charged whenever something is queried.
If what I am saying is incorrect, I would be very grateful for insights into how reads are actually charged.


That is, if I query an entire collection, but only one document is new, I am only charged one read as long as I have enabled persistence and caching. Is that correct?

No, that is not correct.
By default, all query results come from the backend, and you pay for each document read for each of those queries.  The local cache is only used if the backend isn't available (your app is offline), or your query specifically requests documents from the cache (using the source option) instead of the backend.
From the linked documentation:

By default, a get call will attempt to fetch the latest document snapshot from your database. On platforms with offline support, the client library will use the offline cache if the network is unavailable or if the request times out.
You can specify the source option in a get() call to change the default behavior. You can fetch from only the database and ignore the offline cache, or you can fetch from only the offline cache.

See also:

How to read data only from cache in Firestore?
How to avoid unnecessary Firestore reads with Cache


I see, thank you! Then would it be necessary to implement my own logic to reduce reads. Would it make sense to create a document in the DB which always includes the latest change with a timestamp and compare it to the timestamp of the cache on the device (if that is not an existing feature, I would have to write it myself). Based on that I could then define the source from where the data is supposed to be fetched?

If that meets the needs of your app and its requirements, sure. I would not call that a solution that meets all needs you might have, so that's up to you to work out.  A full discussion of how to implement another caching layer on top of all this is too deep for Stack Overflow.

Do you know whether there is some sort of timestamp in the cache? Or would I have to implement that logic myself?

You get only the contents of the documents that you previously added.  If the data you need isn't in a document, then you have to do something on your own.

Thank you! I have come up with a different approach. I will add a timestamp to each document and query only those documents that have a timestamp that is larger than the newest in the cache. Does that approach make sense to you on first glance?

Sure, but with a date filter you won't capture documents that were deleted on the backend.

Good point. For now I'd probably be okay with that. The data is not very sensitive and if an old document remains in the app for a couple days that is not a big deal.
However, a cleaner approach would, of course, be nicer. Do you maybe have some sources that I could look into for better caching approaches?
